# Cannot add a table to database in visual studio 2015 community

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community and am tying to add a table to my database. When I right-click on Tables under the database, I don't get an Add Table option. All I get are Refresh and Properties option. How can I fix this?

Thanks,

Bob Gatto

[image: Display of what it looks like]

Answer (score 0):

Then there is something wrong with your installation of VS. Either, re-install `visual studio` (or) repair it by going to `Control Panel` -> select `visual Studio` and select `Repair` option.

Also make sure you have installed [`SQL Server Data Tools`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Open the installer by going to **Programs and Features** then find **Microsoft Visual Studio _____ 201_**. If you click to **Change** the program it will open the installer for Visual Studio. I recommend that you first **Modify** the program and check that SQL Server Data Tools is installed. If it is then try the **Repair** option.

These steps helped me when I stumbled upon this question that matched my own.